# Azure Signalr Service Connection issue

Tags: c#, angular, azure-signalr

My .NET Core Web API (Version 2.2 )project Can't able to successfully make connection with Azure SignalR service (free tier). its showing some error is like "Failed to connect to the service, will retry after the back off period. Error detail: Unable to connect to the remote server. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.."
my .net core is containerized by local docker installed in my machine and deployed it on the local kubernates clusters.  When i deployed the same thing i local iis its working perfectly.

My client application is based on Angular 7.

Tried some of the SSL certificate workarounds like importing azure ssl certificate to browser but issue has not yet resolved.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddCors();
  services.AddSingleton < IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider > ();
  services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(connection => {
    connection.ConnectionString = "my_connectionstring";
  });
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Expected : Azure signalr Connection need to start and able to send message to clients.

Actual :  Failed to connect to the service, will retry after the back off period. Error detail: Unable to connect to the remote server. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure..

Comment: Did you figure out this? I have a similar problem, it has become a blocker now.

Comment: @Sujith What is the resolution for above blocker?